# USB Keypad Device Preventing Sleep (Windows 11)

Tags: usb, sleep, screensaver, windows-11, powercfg

I've read [USB Audio Device Preventing Sleep (Windows 10)](https://superuser.com/questions/1042932/usb-audio-device-preventing-sleep-windows-10), [Gamepad Prevents Screensaver From Starting on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/979855/gamepad-prevents-screensaver-from-starting-on-windows-10), and a few others on this site.

I have a [TACTICAL ASSAULT COMMANDER F14 FINAL FANTASY® XIV EDITION](https://stores.horiusa.com/tactical-assault-commander-f14-final-fantasy-xiv-edition-pre-order-only-available-october-2021/), and it's preventing my device from idling.

I've found [DiscordNotificationDebug](https://github.com/xaviergmail/DiscordNotificationDebug/) which is how I've identified that my system won't idle only when this TAC keypad is plugged in (so I don't get Discord notifications, among other things like my computer not activating screen saver).

I have tried:

1. Editing group policy for these settings:

```
Allow applications to prevent automatic sleep (plugged in) DISABLED
Allow applications to prevent automatic sleep (on battery) DISABLED
Turn on the ability for applications to prevent sleep transitions DISABLED
Allow standby states (S1-S3) when sleeping (plugged in) ENABLED
Allow standby states (S1-S3) when sleeping (on battery) ENABLED
```

2. Calling powercfg -requestoverride like so (I can't quite tell what the device is registered under):

```
powercfg.exe -requestsoverride DRIVER "*USB*" SYSTEM DISPLAY AWAYMODE
powercfg.exe -requestsoverride DRIVER "*HID*" SYSTEM DISPLAY AWAYMODE
```

Is there a way I can definitively stop this behavior and let my computer idle again?

Comment: Are there any driver updates? Uninstall and reinstall it. There's probably something pretty wrong with the driver. [Contact them](https://stores.horiusa.com/support/) they might be able to see what's up, that's a pretty expensive keypad

Comment: @nAZklX Unfortunately I have a hard time identifying the exact device in device manager, since it doesn't have any distinguishing sort of name. It does show up under Devices & Printers, although I can't seem to do much from there. It looks like their support only applies to consoles, too, not PC devices which is strange, but I'll write an email anyway.